# Java project with Gradle is not compiling on Intellij

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I am not able to compile my Java project. The intellij is not able to detect the Java files as well. I did clink "unlink Gradle" and it started happening after that. I want to fix the gradle settings but I am not able to view the options as well. The gradle tab on the right of the intellij is not visible too. Thank you

[image]

Comment: Are you able to compile the project via Gradle on the command line directly? If so, in IntelliJ's Gradle tool window, hit that little refresh button and see if that works.

Comment: the intellij gradle tool disappeared after I clicked unlink gradle.

Comment: Try the "Notifications" tool window, sometimes it will have a notification asking you to reload the Gradle project.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the .idea folder under the project root and reopen the project.

Comment: tried this as well as invalidating caches too.

Comment: Make sure the Gradle and the Gradle Extension plugins are enabled.